# How do I alias a column in Elixir Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I have a legacy database schema that I am trying to normalize with the help of Elixir (Phoenix) and Ecto. The column definitions work fine, but they are horribly names (hooray for technical debt).

Is there a way to alias a column name, i.e. "meetingName" becomes "meeting_name" when displaying and managing it through the generated api? I've looked through the Ecto documentation and can't seem to find it at all.

Example,

```
@primary_key {:meetingId, :integer, []}
@derive {Phoenix.Param, key: :meetingId}
schema "meeting" do
  field :meetingName, :string

  timestamps()
end
```

Comment: Can't you just rename the column?

Comment: There are other legacy applications that access the same database -- so renaming the column isn't really a solution right now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `source` option as [documented here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3). This lets you specify the database column that this field refers to. For example:

```
field :meeting_name, :string, source: :meetingName
```